# There is any impact of minimum sdk is too lower level (as 8 sdk level) and target sdk is higher sdk level (as 23 sdk level) ?

Tags: android

Is there any impact of lowest (minimum sdk) and highest (target sdk) levels in the android project. Is these things may effect the project reliability and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no impact, If you target **SDk level 8 then your app will target 99.8 % of the mobiles** make sure you use **V7 support jar** to make you development process easier. Since no new popular mobiles have 23 yet you can target it to be ready for the future but **Make sure you dont add unwanted permissions as it will make you life difficult also ensure you handle the scenario if permission is declied**.

Comment: ok.... this will not effect the size of the project as it support 8-23 sdk level.

Comment: ni it does not see all the methods and api in android are backward compatible so no issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the targets are there to filter out what your app caters to which android versions. Different SDK levels has different set of new/updated APIs and depreciated APs.

The lower u go , the more devices you are able to target.

More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: What about the set of code which is deprecated  from lower version to upper version ? But in lower version need to use the same code which is deprecated. Is is not efficient way ? Is there any other way also ?

Answer (score 0):

The impact is only in what features you are able to use. For example API 8 doesn't support animations that were introduced in Honeycomb, API 22 doesn't support the optional permissions introduced in Marshmallow etc.

It is still possible to use these features in your app using the TargetApi annotation, but you have to be sure that they will not be run on older devices, usually by using a statement such as this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    // JellyBean specific code goes here
}
else
{
    // Pre-JellyBean code goes here
}
```